# How can I save entries/import/export from XFCE4's "Session and Startup"?

Tags: linux, session, startup, archlinux, manjaro

How can I save entries or preferably import/export from XFCE4's "Session and Startup" utility? Thanks so much for your time!

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found the answer to this so I am going to try and provide the answer to my own question. This will be the first time ever providing an answer so I hope I doing this alright... and hopefully my answer will help someone else who's also trying to backup/restore their "Session and Startup" entries in linux.

How to backup and restore entries for 'Session and Startup' in linux.

***1.)*** Go to home folder and press `Ctrl + H` to make hidden files visible.

***2.)*** Locate and open the folder labeled `.config`

***3.)*** Locate and open the folder labeled `autostart`

***4.)*** Here you will find all of your custom entries where you can easily backup or restore them.

*Note:* your `.config` folder contains many of your programs settings/configurations which can be found each in a seperate folder (if available)... and is a great way to easily backup and restore many of your applications settings/configurations.

Cheers! :)